# convert &uuml; to u

Tags: php, unicode

I'm using a database that contains contacts (fields like name, address, ...). If i'm using in my database a city that contains special chars (like `ü`) or html codes (like `&uuml;`), then how can i convert them to `u`, so when i search for a city that contains that a special char should be shown in the result...

the database is MyISAM and Collation is latin1_swedish_ci (by default)

Comment: Let me get this right. You store HTML entities in the database and want to convert umlauts like `&uuml;` to `u`? Or to `ü`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your database shouldn't contain any HTML codes but symbols itself.
2. With proper collation set, you will find both `ü` and `u` with your query

Edit: [using collations example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html)

Comment: can you tell me how to choose a collation

Comment: @Remus just `select something from some table where some column contents like 'u%'`

Comment: i'm using a lot of european and other chars, should I use utf8_unicode_ci ?

Comment: i just changed the table to utf8 and the fields from &uuml; to ü, and when i run the query it doesn't recognize ü as u (no match found)

Comment: @Remus see addon to my post please

Answer (score 2):

you probably want to look at this article for other ideas and tools for how to solve your search problem. Normalizing your database search to latin-1 characters isn't the right solution.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/accent-folding-for-auto-complete/